# Mutably borrowing two fields of a pinned struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm trying to make an async version of `BufReader` and the `Lines` struct, but I'm having problems because I need to mutably borrow two fields at once.  It works without the `Pin`, because the compiler can recognize directly borrowing the fields, but it can't do that when it gets the reference from the `DerefMut` on the Pin.  The futures `Stream` trait requires the self type to be a `Pin<&mut Self>`, so I can't just use the normal self type.  How can I convince the compiler that this is safe, or otherwise use `unsafe` to do it myself?

Here's my example:

```
#![feature(arbitrary_self_types, pin)]
use std::pin::Pin;

pub struct Example {
    a: Vec<u32>,
    b: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Example {
    pub fn next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>) {
        let a = &mut self.a;
        let b = &mut self.b;
        a.push(b.remove(0));
    }
}
```

My more complicated example requires using `Read` to write to a slice, so I need to have mutable references to both fields at the same time.

Comment: Your example compiles when you first store the value from b in a temporary and then push it  to a. I'm assuming this is harder to do in your actual use case? (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e26e4e27ff1c93ee44b3bedff29dbdd3)

Comment: As I added at the bottom of the question, I need to have mutable borrows to both at the same time, as I am reading data (Read trait, requires mut) and writing it into a slice (requires mut).

Comment: The duplicate [applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12de122964d06a0a45f0cd772913206e); TL;DR: `let tmp = &mut *self; tmp.a.push(tmp.b.remove(0));`

Comment: That works. Thank you!